A viewcontroller(vca) and another vcb, I need to add vcb.view to vca.view as a subview
Here is a viewcontroller(vca) and another vcb, I need to add vcb.view to vca as a subview.
but I did not use addChildViewController, instead, I directly calls [vca.view addSubview:vcb.view], and vcb's viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear just get called automatically.
really want to know why.
Is addChildViewController necessarily while adding another vc's view as subview?
`ViewControllerA.m

(void)showVCBView {
ViewControllerB *vcb = [[ViewControllerB alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:vcb.view];
}`


UIViewController or NSViewController? Storyboard? How are the view controllers and views instantiated? Post a [mre] please.

addChildViewController is not strictly necessary. You can simply instantiate a controller and add its view as a subview.
However -- if you have any code in vcb, that code will be lost if you do not add the controller as a child.
